# Adding character to specific words in a string

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to add a single character ("n") to a string (a) to the end of each word that have more than 4 characters.

For example, thats the string:

```
a <- "Telefone und Faxgeräte"
```

I've already tried a few approaches using magrittr and stringr. But it doesn't work.

```
str_split(a, " ") %>% for(i in .) {toString(ifelse(str_detect(i, regex("[a-z]{4,}", ignore_case = TRUE)), yes = paste(i, "n", sep = ""), no = i))} %>% print(.)
```

The expected result should be

```
"Telefonen und Faxgeräten"
```

Can someone help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be enough for your use:

```
gsub( "(?<=\\S{4}\\b)", "n", a, perl=TRUE )
```

It looks for any part of the string that contains 4 *non whitespace* characters followed by a *word boundary*.

Now that *word_boundary* doesn't handle `ä` on my system, it might do on yours, depending on localization

If not, try this:

```
gsub( "(?<=\\S{4})(?=(\\s|$|\\.|,|;|:|\\?|!))", "n", a, perl=TRUE )
```

This last approach looks for 4 *non whitespace's* as before, but looks for places where this is followed by a *white space*, end of string, a period, comma, colon or semicolon

EDIT: I'm just adding more characters that I think should not be considered part of a word in most normal texts

Comment: It also doesn't handle ä on my system, but the second solution works for me pretty well.

Thank you for your prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

Use `gsub` with `\\p{L}`, a character class that matches any letter in any language, and backreference `\\1`:

```
gsub("(\\p{L}{4,}\\b)", "\\1n", a, perl = T)
[1] "Telefonen und Faxgeräten"
```

How this works:

- `\\p{L}` matches any letter in any language
- `\\p{L}{4,}` matches any letter in any language occurring at least four times
- `\\b` matches a word boundary
- `(\\p{L}{4,}\\b)` the whole expression as a capturing group so that ...
- `\\1` the backreference in `gsub`'s replacement argument can 'recollect' it and ...
- `n` add to its right an `n` character